# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: ceica

Tags: python, sqlite

> OperationalError
> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: ceica

This is the error message that I receive when I try to delete a row from my databse
Note: I already have implemented functions for adding, searching in tables and worked perfectly fine

HTML button:

```
 {% for row in rows %}
        <p>
            <b>Nume: </b>{{row[1]}} {{row[2]}}, <b>Varsta: </b>{{row[3]}} <br>
            <b>Telefon: </b>{{row[4]}}, <b>Localitate:</b>{{row[5]}}, <b>E-mail: </b>{{row[6]}}
            <button type="button" class="close"><a href="/stergere/pacient/{{row[1]}}">X</a></button>
        </p>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Python function:

```
@auth.route('/stergere/<tabel>/<element>')
def stergereInTabel(tabel,element):
    connection=sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    cursor=connection.cursor()
    if tabel=='pacient':
        #print("DELETE FROM ? WHERE nume=?",(tabel,str(element),))
        #cursor.execute("DELETE FROM ? WHERE nume=?",(tabel,str(element),))
        print("DELETE FROM {} WHERE nume={x}".format(tabel,x=element))
        cursor.execute("DELETE FROM {} WHERE nume={x}".format(tabel,x=element))
    return render_template("{}.html".format(tabel),user=current_user)
```

I tried every combination possible with converting element to string, using .format for both parameters, using tuple method for both but none worked.

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the whole error traceback message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't put quotes around `{x}`, so the `ceica` is being treated as a column name, not a string literal.

You can use string formatting to substitute the table name, but you should use a `cursor.execute()` parameter for values.

```
cursor.execute(f"DELETE FROM {tabel} WHERE nume = ?", (element,))
```

Comment: I tried every way, if I do it as you say, it redirects me to the right page but it doesn t delete the row in my database

Comment: If it's not deleting anything, that means there are no rows that match the condition. Make sure you don't have any extra spaces in `element`.